# Elasticsearch filter out items with _score below average value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "green camouflage bandana",
      "fields": [
        "token_us^1.5",
        "token*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me some set of items with different _scores:

```
"_score": 0.33512896
"_score": 0.29862818
"_score": 0.21525991
"_score": 0.01876816
"_score": 0.00525323
```

So here we have 5 items and average score is 0.17460769. I'd like to have resultset with only 3 items having _score greater then this value. For now I have to read all 5 items, calculate average score and filter out items manually. Is it possible to do this job with some built-in ES functionality?

I know about `min_score` filter but it works only with pre-defined score value.

Comment: have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: Not so. I have used aggregation to calculate avg score, but anyway I have to query ES second time to get items with score > avg

Comment: I also need a solution for that. But maybe querying twice is the only solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43922947/1068246

Comment: @Ololo do you use same query for getting average score? or is there a lightweight one for only getting scores?