# Elasticsearch - Further filter out results based on match score using Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, statistics, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are currently limiting to 50 documents when we are searching in. But score for each document could be very different. eg score of 1st object = 5, score of 50th object = 0.0001. In this case we need to filter out objects with so low score.

What kind of statistical distribution/formula should we use upon querying to the elasticsearch? I am thinking of standard deviation but not so sure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch: Filter out irrelevant results based on score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922588/elasticsearch-filter-out-irrelevant-results-based-on-score)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to have a minimum_score to reduce results. Did you read about the [min_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-search.html#search-api-min-score) parameter?